# ¿Cómo inserto un nodo de forma ascendente en una lista doblemente enlazada en Java?

Tags: java, nodos

La idea es crear un método que agregue un nodo en el lugar que corresponda, dependiendo de si su valor es mayor o menor que el resto, es decir, en manera ascendente.

Tengo esta estructura de nodo:

```
public class Nodo{
    private int value;
    private Nodo siguiente;
    private Nodo anterior;

    public Nodo(int value){
        this.value = value;
        siguiente = null;
        anterior = null;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(Nodo siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }
    public Nodo getSiguiente(){
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setAnterior(Nodo anterior){this.anterior = anterior;}
    public Nodo getAnterior(){return this.anterior;}
}
```

Comment: Hay algo que me causa duda en tu diseño, como accedes al primer nodo de la lista?, deberias tener algun metodo que te devuelva el primer nodo, para asi recorrer cada nodo de la lista comenzando por el primero

Comment: Tengo una clase llamada ListaDobleEnlazada que tiene como atributos el primer nodo y el tamaño de la lista. Esta clase también tiene métodos que te devuelven un nodo en un lugar especifico, remueven un nodo especifico y uno que inserta un nodo al principio o al final de la lista. @Japv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void InsertarNodo(Nodo n)
{
    int tamañoLista = listaDoble.GetTamañoLista();

    if(tamañoLista == 0)
    {
        //Inserto el nodo como el primer nodo de la lista, ya que esta se encuentra vacía.
        //Incremento el tamaño de la lista ya que se añadió un nuevo nodo
    }
    else if(tamañoLista > 0) // Si el tamaño de la lista es mayor que cero quiere decir que existe al menos un nodo en la lista
    {
       Nodo nodoActual = listaDoble.GetPrimerNodo();

       if(tamañoLista == 1)
       {
          if(nodoActual.getValue() >= n.getValue())
          {
             nodoActual.SetAnterior(n);
          }
          else
          {
             nodoActual.SetSiguiente(n);
          }

          //Incrementamos el tamaño de la lista ya que se añadió un nuevo nodo
       }
       else
       { 
          Nodo ultimoNodo = listaDoble.GetUltimoNodo();

          if(nodoActual.getValue() >= n.getValue())
          {
             nodoActual.SetAnterior(n);   
             //Incrementamos el tamaño de la lista ya que se añadió un nuevo nodo        
          }
          else if(ultimoNodo.getValue() <= n.getValue())
          {
             ultimoNodo.setSiguiente(n);
             //Incrementamos el tamaño de la lista ya que se añadió un nuevo nodo
          }
          else 
          {
             while (nodoActual != null)
             {
                if(nodoActual.getValue() <= n.getValue())
                {
                   nodoActual = nodoActual.getSiguiente();
                }
                else
                {
                   Nodo tmpNodo = nodoActual.getAnterior();

                   n.setSiguiente(nodoActual);
                   nodoActual.setAnterior(n);
                   n.setAnterior(tmpNodo);
                   tmpNodo.setSiguiente(n);
                  //Incrementamos el tamaño de la lista ya que se añadio un nuevo nodo
                   break;
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

El siguiente algoritmo es una función que va a insertar un nodo según corresponda, tal como planteas en tu pregunta. La función recibe un parámetro del tipo **Nodo** y no devuelve nada, por lo que es **void**.

Lo primero que hacemos es obtener el tamaño de la lista, si ese tamaño es igual a cero entonces quiere decir que la lista está vacía, por lo tanto lo añadimos a la lista como el primer elemento de la misma e incrementamos el tamaño de la lista ya que se añadió un nuevo nodo.

De no ser cero el tamaño de la lista quiere decir que existe al menos un nodo en la misma.

Si el tamaño de la lista es **1**, preguntamos si ese nodo de la lista tiene su valor mayor o igual que el valor del nodo que tratamos de insertar, de ser mayor o igual entonces añadimos el nuevo nodo antes del primer nodo mediante la instrucción:

```
nodoActual.SetAnterior(n);
```

Caso contrario lo añadimos después:

```
nodoActual.SetSiguiente(n);
```

En ambos casos incrementamos el tamaño de la lista ya que se añadió un nuevo nodo.

En caso de que la lista tenga más de un elemento, procedemos de la siguiente forma preguntando por ambos extremos de la lista, es decir, el primer y último nodo de la lista. Preguntamos si el nodo actual(que en este caso es también el primer nodo) es mayor o igual que el nodo que queremos insertar, de cumplirse esta condición quiere decir que el nodo que queremos insertar al tener su valor menor o igual que el primer nodo iría antes de este, pasando a ocupar la primera posición de la lista.

Sino se cumple esto analizamos el otro extremo de la lista, para ello obtenemos el último nodo de la lista y preguntamos si el valor del último nodo de la lista es menor o igual que el valor del nodo que queremos insertar, de cumplirse esta condición quiere decir que el nuevo nodo que queremos insertar va después de este último nodo, por tanto se insertará como el último nodo de la lista.

En caso de que no se cumplan las condiciones para los extremos de la lista quiere decir que el nodo que queremos insertar iría entonces en alguna posición entre los extremos de la lista.

Para ello ejecutamos un **ciclo while** que se ejecutará mientras el nodo actual no sea **null**.

Dentro de este **ciclo while** vamos navegando por cada nodo siguiente de la lista, siempre y cuando se cumpla la condición, de que el valor del nodo actual es menor o igual que el valor del nodo que queremos insertar. En caso de que esta condición no se cumpla quiere decir que ya encontramos la posición donde iría este nuevo nodo en la lista.

Para insertar este nuevo nodo en la lista tenemos que hacer lo siguiente:

```
Nodo tmpNodo = nodoActual.getAnterior();

n.setSiguiente(nodoActual);
nodoActual.setAnterior(n);
n.setAnterior(tmpNodo);
tmpNodo.setSiguiente(n);
```

En este código reajustamos los enlaces anterior y siguiente entre los nodos para poder insertar el nuevo nodo en la posición que le corresponde. Gráficamente sería como en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como el nuevo nodo que queremos insertar tiene un valor **4**, entonces iría entre el nodo con valor **3** y el nodo con valor **5**, por tanto "rompemos" el vínculo entre el nodo **3** y **5**, y creamos un nuevo vínculo entre el nodo **3** y el nuevo nodo(**4**), y entre el nuevo nodo(**4**) y el nodo **5**.

**Nota:** Como dices que ya tú tienes funciones que te devuelven el primer y el último nodo pues yo utilizo las **funciones GetPrimerNodo** y **GetUltimoNodo** para simular estas funciones.

Revisa bien el código, por supuesto este algoritmo puede ser mucho más optimizado.