# Ingresar un número en una posición y desplazar los demás de su derecha en un Array

Tags: java

tengo un ejercicio dónde debo pedir la posición de en "x" vector, y un número a reemplazar en esa posición, tal que sí:

**vector** = {23, 4, 78, 12, 4, 59}

**Posición**: 2

**Nuevo número:** 100

**vector** = {23, 4, 100, 78, 12, 4}

De tal forma que se desplazaron los números hacia la derecha y el último se pierde.

Yo tengo una parte del código pero no es completa porque no me mueve todos los números
a la derecha... alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/537053/edit) y agrega el código que tienes aunque no funcione. Así demuestras lo que has intentado y evitas que te cierren la pregunta. Una de las normas de la comunidad es que debes demostrar tu intento por resolver el problema.

Comment: revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440240/como-inserto-un-nodo-de-forma-ascendente-en-una-lista-doblemente-enlazada-en-ja/440607#440607